# Why isn't this foreach/dopar function using all the cores I asked for?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, domc

I'm trying to use `doMC` with `foreach` and `%dopar%`. Here is the function:

```
doTheMath_MC <- function(st, end, nd) {

    print(getDoParWorkers())    
    if (st > end) stop("end must be larger than st")

    # Helper function from stackoverflow.com/a/23158178/633251
    tr <- function(x, prec = 0) trunc(x * 10^prec) / 10^prec

    # Function to use with foreach
    fef <- function(i, j, num, trpi) {
        if (num[j] >= num[i]) return(NULL)
        val <- num[i]/num[j]
        if (!tr(val, nd) == trpi) return(NULL)
        return(c(i, j, tr(val, nd)))
        }

    # Here we go...

    nd <- nd - 1
    trpi <- tr(pi, nd)
    num <- st:end
    ni <- length(num)

    ans <- foreach(i = 1:ni, .combine = rbind) %:%
        foreach(j = 1:ni, .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
            fef(i, j, num, trpi)
            }
    cat("Done computing", paste("EST", st, end, nd+1, sep = "_"), "\n")
    if (is.null(ans)) return(NULL)
    ans <- as.matrix(na.omit(ans)) # probably not needed in MC version
    return(ans) # c("num", "den", "est", "eff")
    }
```

I've previously set up the cores and another function calls the function above (this info posted below, I don't think it is the problem).  `getDoParWorkers()` reports that 7 cores have been assigned as intended.  The `cat` statement verifies that the 2 'loops' are working correctly as far as output goes. However, only 1 core is used.  Anyone see why?  Mac OSX 10.10.2 and R 3.2 (2015-03-15 r67992).  Finally, using `doParallel` to control everything gives the same result.

The steps which set up everything:

```
mn <- 1
mx <- 10000
jmp <- 1000
mc <- TRUE

if (mc)     {
    require("doMC")
    registerDoMC(7)
    }

st <- seq(mn -1, mx - jmp, jmp) + 1
end <- seq(mn - 1 + jmp, mx, jmp)
nd <- rep(1:15, each = mx/jmp) # watch the recycling

df <- data.frame(st = st, end = end, nd = nd)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    findEsts(df$st[i], df$end[i], df$nd[i], MC = mc)
    }
```

Comment: Are there any warnings that are outputted when running this? Have you been able to successfully use parallel processing on that computer (and partition) before?

Comment: No warnings.  The `bootMC` example from `doMC` runs correctly.  I am running this with `R CMD batch` from the terminal.  Restarting R doesn't matter. Thanks.

Comment: I've done a bit of testing, and I noticed that the parallel backend is used more fully when each iteration in the inner loop takes a longer time to compute.  If I had to take a rough guess, it would only compute if it's efficient to do so.  This is also true for single (non-nested loops).  If I were you, I would try running the outer loop in parallel, and then running the inner loop normally.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try that.  It occurred to me (while I couldn't sleep!) that the way I wrote fef was probably 'de-vectorizing' the process, so that only one computation was done at a time. I think this is similar to what you are saying.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. When the tasks are very short, the workers use very little CPU time, so you only see the CPU time consumed by the master process. By executing the inner loop sequentially, you may make the tasks CPU intensive enough that it's worthwhile to execute the outer loop in parallel, and then the workers will use significant CPU time.

Comment: Thanks @SteveWeston Now I have to think about how to go about it.  I'm trying to divide all the integers from 1:n by all integers 1:n, looking for rational approximations of pi.  In this case, it's easy to get data structures that are way too large, and hence I was doing each step explicitly, only keeping the relevant stuff so I didn't have RAM issues.  I shall ponder...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question!  I changed the `dopar` handling so that only the outer loop is made parallel:

```
ans <- foreach(i = 1:ni, .combine = rbind) %dopar%
   for (j in 1:ni) {
   fef(i, j, num, trpi)
   }
```

And, I was simply not asking for enough iterations.  For testing, I had been using `mx = 10000` and `jmp = 1000` (see original question).  These were not large enough to trigger parallel processing apparently.  Increasing each 10x was necessary to get parallel processing going.  Thanks to the commenters!

NOTE: While the code above activates the parallel processing, it does not return the answer correctly.  That will be the subject of another question.